# Partial specialization with variadic template parameters that are followed by other parameters

Tags: c++, gcc, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I have an issue with partial specialization involving variadic template parameters. Specialization with a prefix

```
template<typename A, typename ... B>
struct Foo<A, B...> { };
```

work as expected, but when I try to match with postfix

```
template<typename A, typename ... B>
struct Foo<B..., A> { };
```

it somehow doesn't work. Is there some rule that I dont' know about or is that a compiler issue? (I'm using G++ 7.4, specifically x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ from cygwin)

Self contained example to demonstrate my problem:

```
#include <iostream>

template<char ... C>
struct Str
{
    static constexpr char Value[] = { C..., '\0' };
};

template<char ... C>
constexpr char Str<C...>::Value[];

template<typename>
struct TrimFront;

template<char A, char ... C>
struct TrimFront<Str<A, C...>>
{
    typedef Str<C...> Type;
};

template<typename>
struct TrimBack;

template<char A, char ... C>
struct TrimBack<Str<C..., A>>
{
    typedef Str<C...> Type;
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    typedef Str<'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'> str_t;
    std::cout << str_t::Value << std::endl; // prints "abcdef"
    std::cout << TrimFront<str_t>::Type::Value << std::endl; // prints "bcdef"
    std::cout << TrimBack<str_t>::Type::Value << std::endl; // ERROR (incomplete type)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem is a deduced variadic list must be in last position; so `A, B...` is ok, `A..., B` doesn't works.

Comment: @max66 really? very unfortunate. can you by chance point to where it says so in the standard? i cannot seem to find the relevant part.

Comment: I confess that I'm not a language lawyer; but I've added an answer trying to respond to your question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that

```
template<char A, char ... C>
struct TrimBack<Str<C..., A>>
{
    typedef Str<C...> Type;
};
```

cannot works ("`A`" and "`C...`") can't be deduced because the variadic pack (`C...`) isn't in last position.

The OP, reasonably, ask for a reference

> really? very unfortunate. can you by chance point to where it says so in the standard? i cannot seem to find the relevant part

I'm not a language layer but seems to me the relevant part (C++11 standard) is 14.8.2.5 ("Deducing template argument from a type", "[temp.deduct.type]"), point 9 (emphasis mine)

> If `P` has a form that contains `<T>` or `<i>`, then each argument `P_i` of the respective template argument list `P` is compared with the corresponding argument `A_i` of the corresponding template argument list of `A`. **If the template argument list of `P` contains a pack expansion that is not the last template argument, the entire template argument list is a non-deduced context**. If `P_i` is a pack expansion, then the pattern of `P_i` is compared with each remaining argument in the template argument list of `A`. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by `P_i`.

So, if I'm not wrong, `TrimBack<str_t>` (a.k.a. `TrimBack<Str<'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'>>`) gives error because

1) in a first phase, `Str<C..., A>` matches `Str<'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'>`

2) but in a second phase, trying to deduce `C...` and `A` types, `P` (that is `Str<C..., A>`, in this phase) "contains a pack expansion that is not the last template argument", so "the entire template argument list is a non-deduced context".

Answer (score 1):

A partial class template specialization like this

```
template<typename> struct TrimBack;
template<char ...C, char A> struct TrimBack<Str<C..., A>> {}
```

is not allowed, because to deduce `C...` and `A`, [deduction from a type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.fct.spec#temp.deduct.type-1) is performed, and a pack argument that is not last makes it a [non-deduced context](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.fct.spec#temp.deduct.type-9).

What you can do instead is use a helper type to "unwrap" the pack and then "re-wrap" it, less the last element.

```
template <char ...P>
struct dummy {};

template <class T, char ...P>
struct internal;

template <char ...P1, char T, char ...P2>
struct internal<dummy<P1...>, T, P2...>
{
    using type = typename internal<dummy<P1..., T>, P2...>::type; // unwrap one recursively
};

template <char ...P1, char T>
struct internal<dummy<P1...>, T>
{
    using type = Str<P1...>; // re-wrap all but the last one
};

template <typename>
struct TrimBack;

template <char ...C>
struct TrimBack<Str<C...>>
{
    using Type = typename internal<dummy<>, C...>::type;
};
```

Now this should work:

```
std::cout << TrimBack<str_t>::Type::Value << std::endl;  // prints "abcde"
```

[Live demo](https://rextester.com/MXMER47342)

Comment: I confess that I'm confused by the standard but... are you sure that (8.5) from 14.5.5 apply in this case? I mean... in this case "argument" is "`Str<C..., A>`" or "`C...`"?

Comment: i was afraid it might not be legal to match with a variadic template parameter pack that's not at the end. thanks for the offered solution, but like Richard Hodges answer an approach with O(N) complexity is not ideal.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no O(1) solution unfortunately, at best you can make it O(logN) with some smart TMP, but it's going to be much less readable. Remember we're talking about compile-time work only. @max66 I think you're right, I updated my answer.

Comment: I'm agree with first reference (14.8.2.5 point 1, "deduction from a type") but the second one (point 5.6, "non-deduced contect") is about functions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `boost::mp11`:

Comments inline:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>

template<char ... C>
struct Str
{
    static constexpr char Value[] = { C..., '\0' };
};

template<char ... C>
constexpr char Str<C...>::Value[];

template<typename>
struct TrimFront;

template<char A, char ... C>
struct TrimFront<Str<A, C...>>
{
    typedef Str<C...> Type;
};

template<typename>
struct TrimBack;



using namespace boost::mp11;

// a means of turning chars into types
template<char c> struct c_char {
    constexpr char value() { return c; }
 };

// a means of turning an mp_list of c_char<char>... back into a Str<char...>
 template<typename>
 struct back_to_Str;

 template<char...cs>
 struct back_to_Str<mp_list<c_char<cs>...>>
 {
     using result = Str<cs...>;
 };

// TrimBack using types as computation steps:
template<char... C>
struct TrimBack<Str<C...>>
{ 
    // turn the input chars into an mp_list of c_char
    // always use types, they're much easier than values when metaprogramming
    using input = mp_list<c_char<C>...>;        

    // reverse the list
    using reversed = mp_reverse<input>;

    // pop the front c_char<>
    using popped = mp_pop_front<reversed>;

    // reverse again
    using re_reversed = mp_reverse<popped>;

    // turn back into a Str<char...>
    using Type = typename back_to_Str<re_reversed>::result;
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    typedef Str<'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'> str_t;
    std::cout << str_t::Value << std::endl; // prints "abcdef"
    std::cout << TrimFront<str_t>::Type::Value << std::endl; // prints "bcdef"
    std::cout << TrimBack<str_t>::Type::Value << std::endl; // prints "abcde"
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
abcdef
bcdef
abcde
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/387e5dc7ef262f1f

With our new-found knowledge, we can simplify:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>

using namespace boost::mp11;

template<char c> 
struct c_char {
    static constexpr char value() { return c; }
};

template<typename...> struct Str;

template<char... C>
struct Str<c_char<C>...>
{
    static constexpr auto size() -> std::size_t { return sizeof...(C) + 1; }
    static constexpr char Value [size()] = { C..., '\0' };
};

template<char...C> using make_Str = Str<c_char<C>...>;

template<typename List>
struct TrimFront
{
    using Type = mp_pop_front<List>;
};

template<typename List>
struct TrimBack
{ 
    using Type = mp_reverse<mp_pop_front<mp_reverse<List>>>;
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    using str_t = make_Str<'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'>;
    std::cout << str_t::Value << std::endl; // prints "abcdef"
    std::cout << TrimFront<str_t>::Type::Value << std::endl; // prints "bcdef"
    std::cout << TrimBack<str_t>::Type::Value << std::endl; // prints "abcde"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, but i'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. i know how to solve the problem i have given (variadic template -> type list -> arbitrary list-manipulating operation -> variadic template), but that was just an example to clarify my question: can i partially specialize with a variadic argument pack that is not at the end: `my_struct<T..., TT>` ? i'm trying to avoid the type-list solution because in the actual use-case the variadic template holds many hundred types; reverse -> pop -> reverse would have quite the performance penalty

Comment: @DaveDanielKessener I see. I am wondering if there's something that could be done with index_sequence and tuples.